# Is it possible for someone to steal a hash digest of the remember token and create a fake cookie using the hashed digest?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, hash

So persistent cookies are vulnerable to session hijacking, and one of the ways of stealing the cookies is by compromising a database containing the remember tokens. The way to prevent this from happening is by storing a hash digest of the remember token instead of the token itself.

My question is: why cant an attacker take the hash digest of the remember token and the signed user id, create new cookies in their browser, and fill those cookies with the stolen hash digests? because as far as i understand wouldnt the BCrypt in the authenticated? method search for the cookies in your browser and decrypt them when they see the stolen hash digests? or is there a way for it to detect if the cookies were user made or site made?

```
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only store a hash of the remember token in the database, and an attacker can steal this hash from the database, he still doesn't know about the token itself.

The cookie though will contain the original token and the browser will send it to the server. Then the server will hash this original token again and compare it to the hash from the database.

If you know only the hash, and cannot retrieve the original token with it, then you cannot prepare the cookie, because it needs the original token. Cryptographical hash algorithms like SHA512 will not allow to "decode" a hash.